# using regular expressions to find non-numeric values in javascript/jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Essentially, I am trying to find any non-numeric values a user enters into a text field.
currently, my code looks like this:

```
    else if(MileInputElement.match([0-9]))
    {
        InvalidEntry= "Non-numeric values"; 
    }
```

However, when I run this, I get an error saying

> Object doesn't support Property or Method "match."

So, what is a better way to handle this?

Comment: Note that `RegExp.prototype.test()` is more appropriate in this case since you don't need to extract something from the string.

Comment: What type is `MileInputElement`? regex only works with strings. If it is an input element, try `MileInputElement.value`

Comment: You can also use the ES6 method `Number.isInteger()` with the polyfill *(since it is not always implemented)*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

Answer (score 2):

Here you are: `\D` for non-digit, `g` for all matches, `match` return an array

```js
alert('a9bc8'.match(/\D/g));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex delimiters and also you need to convert the object to string before applying the match function.

```
else if(JSON.stringify(MileInputElement).match(/[^0-9]/))
    {
        InvalidEntry= "Non-numeric values"; 
    }
```

Comment: how about .match(/\D/) ? also, you're assuming MileInputElement is a regular object, what if it's a HTMLElement?